# custom form validation directive doesn't pass input data

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I wrote a custom form validation directive that just checks if the amount entered is more than a set amount. If it is then it alerts the user, if not, form submits as usual.

The problem I'm having is that the amount I type into the input is not picked up by the controller that pushes this data to storage when I submit the form.

I get this

```
{ "date": "2014-06-17T09:14:51.340Z", "status": false }
```

instead of this

```
{ "amount": 1222, "date": "2014-06-17T09:14:51.340Z", "status": false }
```

//form

```
<form name="removeMoney" ng-submit="removeEntry()" novalidate>

              <label class="error">
                <input
                  type="number"
                  name="subAmount"
                  placeholder="Remove money from wallet"
                  ng-model="subtractAmount"
                  ng-pattern="/^\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,2})?$/"
                  custom-validation />
              </label>

              <small class="error" ng-show="removeMoney.subAmount.$error.customValidation">
                You can't remove more than {{ total | currency:'£' }}
              </small>

              <small class="error" ng-show="removeMoney.subAmount.$error.pattern">
                Please enter values with no/two decimal points only -- 0.00
              </small>

              <button type="submit" ng-disabled="removeMoney.$invalid" class="button postfix alert">Remove</button>

        </form>
```

//controller

```
$scope.removeEntry = function() {
    var date = new Date();

    $scope.walletItems.push({amount:$scope.subtractAmount, date:date, status:false});
    $scope.subtractAmount = "";
    $scope.removeMoney.$setPristine();
}
```

//directive

```
app.directive('customValidation', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require:'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
            var minimum = ctrl.$viewValue;
            if (minimum > scope.total) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('customValidation', false);
            } else {
                ctrl.$setValidity('customValidation', true);
            }
        });
    }
}
});
```

Comment: is their any console error? if not can you setup a fiddler for the problem?

Comment: No console errors no. I'm trying to setup a fiddle. Will post it asap

Comment: One thing I picked up now is, when I don't use the directive and submit the form, all data does get passed and the form works as it should so the problem is definitely in the directive or the way I use it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't return the value. That is why nothing happened when I submit the form.

```
app.directive('customValidation', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require:'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
            var minimum = ctrl.$viewValue;
            if (minimum > scope.total) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('customValidation', false);
            } else {
                ctrl.$setValidity('customValidation', true);
            }
            return value;
        });
    }
}
});
```